# Insert PhP & MySQL user data correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select

Forum residents!

I had a problem with a MySQL and PhP based user system: I want you to display only the data of the user with I am currently logged in. 
The problem is that it also displays data from other users.

There is a MySQL table containing the following columns: id, username, password, email, VPSID. The goal is for each user to display their own VPSID, if the user  logged in.

The site does not write anything or this display the data of all users.

The code:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location: login.php');
}

$hostname = 'blabla..';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = '';

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn) {
    echo "Connection error: " .mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$id."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['VPSID'];
}

?>
```

What have I done wrong and what is the right solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's better to display user details according to the logged user. what is the value of `$id`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I wrote the code incorrectly on the question.
I've upgraded 'mysql_query' to 'mysqli_query', but it doesn't work.

Comment: The "id" contains the number of users.
The first user's serial number is "1" in the id table.

Comment: There is no problem with the MySQL connection, just the selection. The goal is to display users only their own VPSID. Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/cx0yKlW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$id` is null thats your problem.

Maybe `$id = $_SESSION["id"];`

If you dont store it that way go off username since I'm going to guess they are unique

```
$user_name = $_SESSION["username"];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT VPSID FROM users WHERE username ='$user_name'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['VPSID'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with little change! :) `$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT VPSID FROM users WHERE username = '$user_name'");`